# Select a single column from a list of numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of numbers (2, 8, 12, 2, 48, 7...).  I would like to select this list as a single column using MySQL.

I want my results to be:

```
Column 1
--------
2
8
12
2
48
7
```

...

What is the recommended way to do this?

(Edit: Ideally, I would like to do this without resorting to stored procedures or functions.)

Comment: what is the source of this list?is it a comma separated values in a string?

Comment: @Tom Tresansky: Do you mean you want to concatenate all the numbers? e.g. return `2, 8, 12, 7` from a `SELECT` query?

Comment: @stealthyninja, i think he means to do the opposite, turn a list of numbers into multiple rows.

Comment: I want to do as nathan gonzalez suggests, turn a list of numbers into multiple rows within the same column.

Comment: @manji: The source will be input as a comma-separated list of values.

Comment: Do you then plan on joining to this list of Numbers? In order to select from another table?

Comment: @Mark Davidon: I want to be able to do anything I could normally do with a SQL result set: grouping, sorting, joining, etc.  I just want to get from my list to a single column with all my list results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [this procedure](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows).  it seems to be doing exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: While that procedure will probably work, there must be a way to do this using just a SELECT and not resorting to procedures.

Comment: @Tom: Is there a reason you have an aversion to Stored Procedures?

Comment: @FreeAsinBeer: I don't want to have to modify my schema for something that I assume can be done in a SELECT statement.  I assume this because I know you can do this transformation in a SELECT using MS SQLServer.

Comment: @Tom Tresansky, until sql server 2005 the only way to do this in sql server was using a table-valued-function.  the addition of the cross apply made it much simpler, obviously.  you are mistaken if you think there is feature parity between mysql and mssql server 2005+.  heck, mysql just got views and procedures with version 5, iirc.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: Sigh, I didn't realize that was such a new feature.  It seems like such an obvious thing to want to do in any SQL flavour...  I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if anyone knows some way.

Comment: @Tom Tresansky, yeah, mysql can be disappointing in that way.  but then you get cool features like group_concat() and field().

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

I think you may be required to use a Stored Procedure to achieve this functionality. Here's a sample from [forge.mysql](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=4).